# ¿Porqué en este loop de JavaScript la impresión de la variable es desde counter y no desde counter-1?

Tags: javascript, bucles

en mi búsqueda por aprender programación por mis propios medios, me he topado con el tema de recursividad y este simple código... mi pregunta ya que la variable counter comienza desde 10 y dentro del loop While el contador resta 1, porqué en la "impresión" aparece desde el 10. Sé que si quisiera empezar desde 10 colocaría el contador en 11... pero obviamente tengo la curiosidad y no entiendo.

```
var counter = 10;
while(counter > 0) {
    console.log(counter--);
}
```

resultado:
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón es simple, en recursividad lo que haces es pasar una variable o arreglo en la mayor parte de los caso para modificarlos o simplemente imprimirlos, en tu caso quieres restar un numero por cada iteracion dentro de tu ciclo `while` pero aqui lo que tu quieres conseguir es que primero te imprima el 9 por la lógica que encuentras en tu programa y aunque no es del todo errónea eso no sucederá jamas por la siguiente razón.

En tu codigo lo que tienes es la impresion de tu variable e imprimes lo que es `counter--` y a pesar de que si te resta -1 en esa misma iteracion sucede que primero te imprimira la variable antes de hacer dicha operacion ya que es lo que primero lee javascript, es como si tu codigo estuviera dividido en dos partes.

**EJEMPLO**

```
var counter = 10;
while(counter > 0) {
    console.log(counter); // Lee antes el valor variable
    counter--; // Después realiza operación
}
```

Esto sucede asi porque es como funciona internamente lo que realizas con javascript ya que a pesar de que parece un metodo simple de resta internamente esta compuesto de dos partes. Para cuando javascript hace la operacion tu valor ya esta en pantalla.

**EJEMPLO VISUAL**

> **Primera iteración:**
>
> counter = 10 | counter-- | counter = 9
>
> counter = 9 | counter-- | counter = 8
>
> counter = 8 | counter-- | counter = 7
>
> ...
>
> counter = 1 | counter-- | counter = 0
>
> counter = 0 | counter-- | counter = -1 -> En este caso ya no cumples con la condición por lo cual nunca se imprime.

Para realizar el proceso que quieres en el caso de que primero quieras que se imprima el 9 entonces deberas de hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var counter = 10;
while(counter > 0) {
    counter--;
    console.log(counter);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, entendido a la perfección.

Answer (score 2):

**[Operador decremento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos)**

**Post decremento**

El operador de post decremento  (`counter--`) en Javascript (y en los lenguajes que lo implementan) realiza lo siguiente:

1. Devuelve el valor de la variable `counter` al método en la que fue llamada o en la asignación realizada.
2. Realiza la operación de decremento.

Es por esto que tu método `console.log` imprime el valor que tiene la variable `counter` antes de realizar el decremento, y luego recién se realiza el mismo.

Dado que tu variable está iniciada en `10`, este será el primer valor mostrado en pantalla.

Una forma de ver esto en acción sería:

```js
let counter = 10;

while(counter > 0) {
  console.log(counter--);
  console.log(`Ahora counter es: ${counter}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Pre decremento**

A diferencia de su contraparte, este operador realiza previamente el decremento y luego devuelve el valor del resultado al método o asignación en la que es llamado, por ejemplo:

```js
let counter = 10;

while(counter > 0) {
  console.log(`Antes counter vale: ${counter}`);
  console.log(--counter);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

El resultado de este bucle (si eliminas la primera llamada de `console.log`) debe ser: `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`, a diferencia de cuando se usa el post decremento.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda

Comment: Gracias. a ver si este punto de vista es correcto?... cuando en la 1° vuelta: se imprime 10 el contador baja a 9...en la segunda vuelta se imprime nueve y el contador baja a 8...y así. sucesiv... aunque todo se imprime al finalizar el loop completo.

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que sucede, en cada vuelta, sea que uses post decremento o pre decremento. Lo que varía es lo que se muestra en pantalla cuando usas el operador de decremento dentro del método `console.log`. Cuando usas post decremento se mostrará el valor antes de ser restado, si usas pre decremento se mostrará el valor ya restado. Pero independientemente de esto, en cada vuelta el valor es reducido. Esto quiere decir, que en cada vuelta el valor de `counter` será una unidad menor que el que tenía en la vuelta anterior.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que me parece mas acertada a la pregunta realizada +1 y elimino la mia ya que esta esta mucho mas detallada

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento se esta dando por la posición que cumple el oprador de decremento; es decir:

- Si el operador de decremento esta después, entonces hace la comparación y luego decrementa en 1 a la cantidad original

Código

```
let numero = 10
console.log(numero--)
```

Y tenemos como resultado:

> 10

En cambio:

- Si usamos el operador de decremento al inicio, le indicamos que decremente o reste 1 a la cantidad original y luego proceda con la comparación:

Código

```
let numero = 10
console.log(--numero)
```

Nos dará como resultado

> 9